# How to set consistency level on a query basis in Java Spring Data Cassandra Reactive Library

Tags: java, spring, cassandra, spring-webflux

I am using Spring Data Cassandra reactive library in Java and using ReactiveCqlTemplate to query ScyllaDB.

On an application level, we can set by specifying property as below in the application.properties file

spring.data.cassandra.consistency-level=quorum

My question is how do I specify consistency level on a per-query level using ReactiveCqlTemplate? I am using ReactiveCqlTemplate to query my Scylla DB. The code sample is as below:

```
@Autowired
private ReactiveCqlTemplate template;

@Override
public Mono<Template> findTemplate(Channel channel, String id) {
    String query = "select * from task where id = ? and channel = ?";
    
    return template.queryForObject(query,  new RowMapper<Template>() {
        public Template mapRow(Row row, int rowNum) {
          Template template = new Template();
          template.setContent(row.getString("content"));
          template.setMessageType(row.getString("message_type"));
          template.setSource(row.getString("source"));
          template.setSubject(row.getString("subject"));
          template.setTemplateKey(new TemplateKey(row.getString("id"), Channel.fromString(row.getString(("channel")))));
          return template;
        }}, UUID.fromString(id), channel.toString());
}
```

There is an option to set ConsistencyLevel in using the template variable above but that would be for the whole object. I would like to specify on each-query I am shooting to Scylla DB.

Answer (score 1):

If you insist on using `ReactiveCqlTemplate` you are forced to use [QueryBuilder](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/4.9/manual/query_builder/) to build queries and then [setConsistency](https://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/4.0/com/datastax/oss/driver/api/core/cql/Statement.html#setConsistencyLevel-com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.ConsistencyLevel-) level on your [SimpleStatements](https://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/4.0/com/datastax/oss/driver/api/core/cql/SimpleStatement.html).

Otherwise you can use `ReactiveCassandraTemplate` and you will have an option to pass in QueryOptions for each statement.

Or even better if you use the repository you can just annotate your queries with `@Consistency( ... )`

You have selected the lowest level so then you need to use the drivers classes and get no abstraction help from spring.

[Choosing An Approach](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/cassandra/docs/current/reference/html/#cassandra.choose-style)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The reason of choosing ReactiveCqlTemplate is it provides an easy way where you can pass CQL queries and it converts them to PreparedStatement and eventually helps in performance of DB as it doesn't have to parse the query each time on DB. If ReactiveCassandraTemplate does that, I can use that

Comment: I dont know what works best for you, the higher abstraction level the more you get ”for free”. Only you know what fits your buisness needs. But as mentioned in the answer, the lower you go then the more yuo need to work with the drivers classes. I usually start with the highest of abstractions first, then i go lower and lower if needed.